# IPv6 Not Routing Properly

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2012, rras

I am setting up a RRAS machine for my personal use and for use by a few of my friends.  I am currently using Windows Server 2012; but I have tried this with Windows Server 2008 R2.  Both systems didn't quite work as expected.

I have tried getting OpenVPN to work on Debian 6 but had no luck.  In the end, I am hoping for something that is easy to use client side and works.

On my RRAS machine, I have it configured with a static IPv6 address from my routed /48 via HE.net.  (All IPv6 access is controlled by a CentOS 6 VM, and it provides network wide ipv6 connectivity)  The RRAS machine can talk to VPN Clients & the Internet/Intranet over IPv6 as it should.  VPN Clients can talk to the Internet, Intranet & the RRAS server over IPv4; but they can only talk to the RRAS server over IPv6.  Which leads me to believe it is a routing issue on the RRAS Server.  In addition, LAN (To the RRAS Server) CANNOT ping any connected VPN client over IPv6 but can ping over IPv4.

Now Current Configuration

On my CentOS VM I have the route table configured to properly redirect out to the RRAS server for the /48.

On my RRAS server I have assigned 2001:XXX:XXXX:XXXX::1 to its interface, again it is from my /48.

In the RRAS console, I've set the IPV6 prefix to the same as the interface prefix.  I've also enabled IPv6 Remote Access Server and IPv6 Routing on LAN/Dial Connections.

In theory IPv6 Should be working at this point.  But with tracerts & pathpings all responses stop at the Internal Interface for the RRAS server.

Via netsh int ipv6, I have the LAN connection & the RRAS Dialin connection set to IPv6 Forward enabled.

Below is netsh int ipv6 show route & ipconfig /all on the server  (xxxx:yyyy is the same on all points it is used)

```
    Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
-------  --------  ---  ------------------------  ---  ------------------------
Yes      Manual    256  ::/0                       13  2001:470:89d1::1
No       System    256  ::1/128                     1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
Yes      System    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    13  Internet
Yes      Manual    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
No       System    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/128   21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
No       System    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::1/128   13  Internet
No       System    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy:86d:bb9c:f65e:3197/128   21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
No       System    256  fe80::/64                  13  Internet
No       System    256  fe80::/64                  21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
No       System    256  fe80::86d:bb9c:f65e:3197/128   21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
No       System    256  fe80::ad8b:7bf1:399b:581f/128   13  Internet
No       System    256  ff00::/8                    1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  ff00::/8                   13  Internet
No       System    256  ff00::/8                   21  RAS (Dial In) Interface

IPConfig
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-PJJOFHDSB3G
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx:yyyy:86d:bb9c:f65e:3197(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::86d:bb9c:f65e:3197%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369101865
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-E7-DD-ED-00-0C-29-64-6D-AB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Internet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-64-6D-B5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::1(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad8b:7bf1:399b:581f%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.25(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx::1
                                       192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx::1
                                       192.168.1.3
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Route & IPconfig on Win7 Client

```
Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
-------  --------  ---  ------------------------  ---  ------------------------
No       Manual    256  ::/0                       12  fe80::86d:bb9c:f65e:3197
No       Manual    256  ::1/128                     1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       Manual    8    2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    12  VPN Connection
No       Manual    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    12  fe80::86d:bb9c:f65e:3197
No       Manual    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy:d4a6:f3b8:b796:72/128   12  VPN Connection
No       Manual    256  fe80::/64                  12  VPN Connection
No       Manual    256  fe80::d4a6:f3b8:b796:72/128   12  VPN Connection
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                    1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface
 1
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                   12  VPN Connection

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-PPK6F59AAS4
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : amwdrizz.com

PPP adapter VPN Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VPN Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx:yyyy:d4a6:f3b8:b796:72(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4a6:f3b8:b796:72%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::86d:bb9c:f65e:3197%12
                                       0.0.0.0
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335678752
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-4F-B6-87-00-0C-29-AF-54-0F

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::1
                                       192.168.1.3
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : amwdrizz.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-AF-54-0F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.162(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 02, 2013 1:15:47 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, April 03, 2013 12:20:51 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I hope that is enough information to try and help me on this.  And I have been reviewing alot of documentation, but sadly there isn't a whole lot on IPv6 & Windows 2008/2012.

Update as of 4/11/2013

I have tried to add neighbors and routes between the interfaces.  But due to the RRAS not having an assigned MAC address, I can't add a neighbor for it.

Still same issue of VPN clients see server, but don't see anything past the server via IPv6.  Still open to suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

```
Yes      System    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    13  Internet
Yes      Manual    256  2001:470:xxxx:yyyy::/64    21  RAS (Dial In) Interface
```

Your Internet subnet and RAS subnet need to be different subnets. Pick one, assign it to your RAS subnet and ensure your IPv6 gateway knows to route that subnet to your RRAS server.